# Psalms 53:2-3 vs Romans 3:10-11 “all turned aside/none seek after God”

Tags: romans, psalms, intertextuality

Between the variants of the Psalms & Romans it would appear that Paul added the words “there is none who seeks after God” when it would also appear he is quoting the psalms:

> “God looks down from heaven upon the children of men, To see if there
> are any who understand, **who seek God**. **Every one of them has turned
> aside**; They have together become corrupt; There is none who does good,
> No, not one.” ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭53:2-3‬

It says: “everyone one of them has turned aside”

**Q**: Yet, is there any reason Paul writes it slightly different in Romans?

> “As it is written: “There is none righteous, no, not one; There is
> none who understands; **There is none who seeks after God**.” ‭‭Romans‬
> ‭3:10-11‬

**Q2**: Is Paul being authorized by the Spirit to write the Psalms slightly differently in Romans?

After all, Paul says “***it is written***”

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote the following texts:

**Rom 3:11, 12** - “There is no one righteous, not even one.  There is no one who understands, no one who seeks God. All have turned away, they have together become worthless; there is no one who does good, not even one.”

**Ps 14:1-3** - The fool says in his heart, “There is no God.” They are corrupt; their acts are vile. **There is no one who does good**. The LORD looks down from heaven upon the sons of men to see if any understand, if any seek God. **All have turned away, they have together become corrupt; there is no one who does good, not even one.**

**Ps 53:1-3** - The fool says in his heart, “There is no God.” They are corrupt; their ways are vile. **There is no one who does good**. God looks down from heaven upon the sons of men to see if any understand, if any seek God. **All have turned away, they have together become corrupt; there is no one who does good, not even one.**

It is immediately apparent that Paul quotes these Psalms quite well.

Comment: I would agree that he writes them well, accurate and altogether true.  Yet, it is apparent that the Spirit of God allowed Paul to change minor words, example: the words “if any seek God, they have all turned aside” & “no one who seeks God” have identical meaning in the text, but slightly different wording.  I still give your answer +1 because I agree with you in part.  It would appear that Paul was (as an apostle) trying to be more straightforward in his writing style.

Comment: @Cork88 - there is no NT quote of an OT passage that is perfectly verbatim.  They all change the text - some only very slightly but some change them much more.  Sometimes this is due to the differences between the MT and LXX - the NT writers almost always quote the LXX more closely.

Comment: Appreciate the insight Dottard, thx.